# Issue with Caliburn Micro's WindowManager Method in WPF - Window Minimization Problem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro, window-managers

I'm encountering an issue with Caliburn Micro (WPF version 4.0.212) where the ShowWindowAsync method from the window manager fails to minimize the window when clicking outside of it. This functionality used to work in the past, but it's no longer behaving as expected. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
public dynamic GetWindowManagerSettings()
{
    dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
    settings.Width = 920;
    settings.Height = 700;
    settings.SizeToContent = 0;
    return settings;
}

public async Task ShowWindowClicked()
{
    var vm = IoC.Get<IPage00ViewModel>();
    await _windowManager.ShowWindowAsync(vm, null, GetWindowManagerSettings());
}
```

The problem arises when the window, opened using `ShowWindowAsync`, doesn't minimize upon clicking outside of it. Previously, this functionality worked as expected. I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on why this behavior might have changed and how to resolve it in Caliburn Micro's WindowManager for WPF.